# using flask SQLAlchemy unable to insert foreign key data

Tags: python, mysql, flask

In the following code snippet, In the **events** table event_id is created first  and then i need to insert multiple records into **even_logins** table based on the event_id.

```
class Events(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'events'
    event_name=  db.column(db.String(100))
    event_id = db.Column(db.String(10),primary_key=True)
    scheduled_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable = False)
    event_logins_event_id = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('event_logins.event_id'))
    event_registrations_event_id = db.Column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('event_registrations.event_id'))


class Event_logins(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'event_logins'
    event_id=  db.column(db.String(10),db.ForeignKey('events.event_id'))
    username = db.Column(db.String(20),primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(300))


class Event_registrations(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'event_registrations'
    event_id=  db.column(db.String(10), db.ForeignKey('events.event_id'))
    registration_id = db.Column(db.String(50),primary_key=True)
    cust_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    cust_contactno = db.Column(db.String(50))
    cust_email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    cust_imageid = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

Finally with the below query am trying insert a record into **event_logins** table

```
 event_logins = Event_logins(event_id='jk12',username='testuser', password='aaaa')
 db.session.add(event_logins)
 db.session.commit()
```

In the table it is stored as NULL the value is not being stored pls suggest

Thanks
vijay

Comment: are you sure event with id = 'jk12' is already stored?

Comment: yes it is already stored in primary key table